# When to use FromUri and when not in an ASP.NET Web API

Tags: asp.net, rest, web-services

I have a working code with some routes like:

```
[Route("Companies/{id}", Name = "CompanyDetails")]
[HttpGet]
public HttpResponseMessage getCompanyDetails(string id)
{...}

[Route("Drivers/{driverIds}/Routes", Name = "Drivers")]
[HttpGet]
public HttpResponseMessage getDrivers([FromUri] List<int> driversId)
{...}

[Route("Vehicles/Signs", Name = "VehicleSigns")]
[HttpGet]
public HttpResponseMessage getVehicleSigns([FromUri]string companyId , [FromUri]List<string> vehicleIds)
{...}
```

From a similar question i learnt that it has to do with the type of the parameter , still i haven't configured out in depth when i have to put **[FromUri]** and when **not** .Does it have to do with the parameter type , the number of parameters or a combination of them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is to do with how Web API binds parameters for an action method.

If you look at the [official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api):

> If the parameter is a "simple" type, Web API tries to get the value
> from the URI. Simple types include the .NET primitive types (int,
> bool, double, and so forth), plus TimeSpan, DateTime, Guid, decimal,
> and string, plus any type with a type converter that can convert from
> a string. (More about type converters later.)
>
> For complex types, Web
> API tries to read the value from the message body, using a media-type
> formatter.

So, to bind a complex type from Uri parameters:

```
public class GeoPoint
{
    public double Latitude { get; set; } 
    public double Longitude { get; set; }
}

public ValuesController : ApiController
{
    public HttpResponseMessage Get([FromUri] GeoPoint location) { ... }
}
```

And then pass the `Latitude` and `Longitude` in URI query string:

```
http://localhost/api/values/?Latitude=47.678558&Longitude=-122.130989
```

If you don't specify `[FromUri]` attribute web api will look for `Longitude` and `Latitude` in the request body by default

Comment: I see , I have read some parts of the docs and i have set some things more clear in my mind . As result of that , i am realizing that my primary issue, was due to the confusion of  route template parameters and the action parameters .  Thanks for your help !